# How to make work a function inside a for statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem with this exercise. They first asked me to write a code to detect if a number is a prime number. This worked pretty well with this piece of code down here:

```
def primo(n):
  resultado = False
  div = 2
  while div**2 <= n:

    if n == 1:
        resultado = False
        div+=1
    if n%div == 0:
      resultado = False   
      return resultado
      div**2 > n
    else:
      resultado = True

    div+=1

  return(resultado)
```

After this, the exercise is asking me to write a for loop to check if any number between 1 and 20 is a prime, so i wrote:

```
for n in range(1,21):
    primo(n)
```

and nothing happens, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primo` return a boolean indicating if the number is prime, but you don't do anything with that value so you never see the result. You probably want something like:

```
for n in range(1, 21):
    is_prime = primo(n)
    print('{} is prime? {}'.format(n, is_prime))
```

Comment: it worked perfectly but now i have another problem, my previous code (the function) doesn't show 2 and 3 as primes. how could i solve these? thanks for your help

Comment: Your code inside while is only executed if div ** 2 >= 4. Since div is set to 2 by default 2**2 = 4 (** is the power function). Since 2 and 3 are less than 4, the while loop is not executed and your result variable stays "False".

Answer (score 0):

Your function `primo()` is returning a boolean which is either True or False. You are not doing anything with that return value. You can do something like that

```
for n in range(1,21):
    out=primo(n)
    print(out) #or whatever you want
```

There is a problem in you primo function as well. For `n=2 & n=3` it will not enter the loop and 3 will show as a non-prime number. I have modified that a little bit.

```
def primo(n):
  resultado = False
  div = 2
  if n == 1:
    resultado = False
    return(resultado)

  while div**2 <= n:
    if n%div == 0:
      resultado = False
      return resultado
    div+=1
```

Comment: it worked perfectly but now i have another problem, my previous code (the function) doesn't show 2 and 3 as primes. how could i solve these? thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try the primo function I wrote above?